# Bypass the single quotes

Tags: workflow, picklist

```
OR(ISPICKVAL(Status,'In Progress- Engineering'),ISPICKVAL(Status,'**In Progress- PLM\'s'**))
```

Comment: But you have to use regeular experssion i think so.But try to use Single quotes can be added like this \\\' @Balaji

Comment: Its not working

Comment: My suggestion is try to do with regular expression like                      REGEX(Name, ".*('|\\.\\z).*")

Comment: picklist value like this " In-Progress-PLM's.  Now we need to write workflow formula..It would be great if get perfect answer.

Comment: AND(OR(ISPICKVAL(Status,'In Progress- Engineering'),ISPICKVAL(Status,'In Progress- PLM\\\'s')), ISBLANK(Opportunity__c), Total_Mod_Cust_Reocords__c > 0)

Comment: Can any write perfect formula ?

Answer (score 1):

in the formula use quotes "

```
OR(ISPICKVAL(Status,"In Progress- Engineering"),ISPICKVAL(Status,"In Progress- PLM's")
```

Also make sure the values you are using are correct. You have no space before the - but a space after. It must be exact

Validated working with a Test Picklist containing "Wilson's" and a formula field to check it:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(TESTFLD__c,"Wilson's"),'YES','NO')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OR(ISPICKVAL(Status,'In Progress- Engineering'),ISPICKVAL(Status,'In Progress- PLM\'s\'))
```

try this, i think this should work @Balaji

Comment: Nope its not working

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for your Support. I solved the problem.

Ans: I have chosen the "created, and every time it's edited" in Evaluation Criteria.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with your question. I am confused